# How to iterate over enum

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

I want to iterate over enum:

```php
enum Shapes
{
    case RECTANGLE;
    case SQUARE;
    case CIRCLE;
    case OVAL;
}
```

I get `Shapes` const not defined if I do this:

```php
foreach (Shapes as $shape) { }
```

The best solution I came with is to manually create array for enum:

```php
$shapes = [
    Shapes::RECTANGLE,
    Shapes::SQUARE,
    Shapes::CIRCLE,
    Shapes::OVAL,
];
foreach ($shapes as $shape) { }
```

Is there any better way to iterate over the enum?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can generates a list of cases on an enum with [cases()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unitenum.php) like this:

```
enum Shapes
{
    case RECTANGLE;
    case SQUARE;
    case CIRCLE;
    case OVAL;
}

foreach (Shapes::cases() as $shape) { 
    echo $shape->name . "\n";
}
```

The output of this is:

```
RECTANGLE
SQUARE
CIRCLE
OVAL
```

for PHP 8.1 and greater.

See: [PHP Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/pJDeb)

Answer (score 5):

You can try `Shapes::cases()` ,it returns an array of all cases of a given Enum.